# Why go get in a repository with go.work throws warning package is not used in this module?

Tags: go

My goal is to create [a repository with multiple folders](https://github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang).

```
|- go.work
|- websocket
|  |- go.mod
|  |- go.sum
|  |- server.go
|- channel
|  |- main.go
```

The websocket uses `github.com/gorilla/websocket` package.

So, I need to do in the `websocket` folder.

1. `$ go mod init github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/websocket`
2. `$ go get github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.5.0`
3. `$ go work use .`

The problem is, the `websocket/go.mod` throws warning

```
github.com/gorilla/websocket is not used in this module
```

If I do `go mod tidy`, the `websocket/go.mod` will be cleaned out and `websocket/server.go` will throws error

```
could not import github.com/gorilla/websocket (no required module provides package "github.com/gorilla/websocket")
```

**TLDR**

websocket/go.mod

```
module github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/websocket

go 1.19

require github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0 // indirect
```

websocket/go.sum

```
github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0 h1:PPwGk2jz7EePpoHN/+ClbZu8SPxiqlu12wZP/3sWmnc=
github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0/go.mod h1:YR8l580nyteQvAITg2hZ9XVh4b55+EU/adAjf1fMHhE=
```

[websocket/server.go](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/server.go)

go.work

```
go 1.19

use (
    ./websocket
)
```

Comment: If the compiler tells you "github.com/gorilla/websocket is not used in this module" than you are not using websocket. Does your code actually **import**  github.com/gorilla/websocket. Note that `go get`-ing a package without actual usage is a programming error.

Comment: @Volker the `websocket/server.go` does import it, `import "github.com/gorilla/websocket"` for the full code, it's in the [gorilla/websocket repository](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/server.go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your `server.go` is in `package main`, as the original [`gorilla/websocket/examples/echo/server.go`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/server.go) is.

Second, test if the name of the folder (which is *also* `websocket`) is an issue (conflicting with the `websocket.xxx` calls).
For testing, try and change it (and update `go.work` accordingly)

Comment: That's the problem. Changing the `websocket` folder to `ws` did the job.